# Difficulty to evaluate a method with the evaluation dataset

Tags: testing, weka, instances

I read about compatibility issues that weka shows when the set of training data and evaluation are different (ie, do not contain the same number of attributes or are in disorderly),  I also had these problems, but the problem for me now is different:

I use a training file with 23 instances and one evaluation with one instance, open the training file, select the method Naïve Bayes and pressed start, So far so good but when I want to evaluate and select the file method of evaluation, no weka acknowledges the request contained in the file, however weka recognizes the number of attributes ...

I click start and evaluates the instance but the report generated by the software indicates that there is no instance, hence the confusion matrix shows no classified instance, anyone who can help me with this problem?